# Can't use c# particleSystem property anymore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, deprecation-warning

I was able before to use in Visual Studio C# code,

```
particleSystem.SetParticles(points, points.Length);
```

but now it gives me an error. Did the syntax change? Do I have to use

```
GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().SetParticles(points, points.Length);
```

now? My VS project (using Unity here) does not display my particles anymore but I have not found any other syntax I could/should be using. Is this correct, and do I have some other error? Or is this incorrect?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it give any particular error?

Comment: @stuartd It tells me that particleSystem.SetParticles() is obsolete and tells me to use the GetComponent line. I used it as they said, but now I have no particles.

Comment: Sure, you now use "GetComponent" for that one - no big deal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the [relevant Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-particleSystem.html), this is another property that has been recently (since version 5.4.0) deprecated.

So yes, you will now have to use `GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()` instead to get a reference to the particle system - and you'll probably want to cache that reference in a variable in the [`Awake()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) method in the event that you need to frequently make use of it.